# How do you make Laravel queue run automatically using Forge and Ubuntu?

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, queue, lumen, supervisord

My queue jobs never reach the handle() function, though the construct() function is called just fine. I have a queue called "api" and I am sending the jobs to that queue. Supervisor is set to run the "api" queue automatically. But the job never gets done. The driver is database, I can see the job going into the jobs table and then being deleted when the queue is completed. The job does not get done but no entries are made to the failed_jobs table.

What am I doing wrong?

Laravel-lumen 7.0.